# Problem with Heroku buildpack stack 20 for Shiny App

Tags: r, heroku, shiny, heroku-cli

I tried to publish Shiny App on Heroku but occured problem with buildpack (i used http://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r.git).

As I read my buildpack is using stack 18 but Heroku require stack 20.

Do You know R Shiny buildpack for stack 20 or other solution? Do I need to use Heroku CLI for Shiny App?

Bellow info from Heroku.

```
Building on the Heroku-20 stack
Using buildpack: http://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r.git
R Shiny app detected
This version of the heroku-buildpack-r is NO LONGER SUPPORTED!
See https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r for details.
ERROR: This version of the buildpack is intended for use with the 'heroku-16' stack
Use the 'heroku stack:set' CLI command to use the 'heroku-16' stack.
See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack for more information.
Push rejected, failed to compile R Shiny app.
Push failed
```

Answer (score 3):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack

Heroku-18 is supported until April 2023

You can set your stack to 18 with the command:

```
heroku stack:set heroku-18
```

Or you wait until the buildpack you want to use supports heroku-20 as well.

Comment: This is Heroku CLI command "heroku stack:set heroku-18" ? Is it possible to change from Heroku GUI?

Comment: There is no Heroku GUI. If you mean the dashboard/website you can only upgrade the stack, not downgrade. To downgrade you have to use the Heroku CLI or define the stack in an `app.json`, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema